# avoid two alert dialogs showing

Tags: android

I am trying to put an alert dialog in my Android app. It's working fine but the problem is after the dialog shows and I click on the main button it show TWO dialog one only title and the other one is title with message content and 2 buttons. This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyFull.this);
alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.sms);    
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.buy, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on buy",    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.cancel();
}
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: replace `alertDialog.show()` with `alertDialog.create().show()`. You need to create alertDialog first and then show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyFull.this);
alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.sms);    
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.buy, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on buy",    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
dialog.cancel();
}
});
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create dialog first before showing it. Just add one line before showing the dialog and it will work like this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyFull.this);
alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.sms);    
alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.buy, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on buy",    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
dialog.cancel();
}
});
AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
dialog.show()
```